# Solving ResolveNuGetPackageAssets target error in Build Pipleline of Azure Devops?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure-devops, csproj, .net-framework-version

My Azure DevOps pipeline build is failing with the below error, also the build in local is building Successfully. All I have tried to upgrade the project framework to > 4.7 from 4.6.1

> (ResolveNuGetPackageAssets target) ->    C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\15.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets(186,5):
> error : Your project does not reference ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"
> framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" in the
> "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet
> restore. [D:\a\1\s\project\project\project.csproj]
>
> ```
> 4 Warning(s)
> 1 Error(s)
> ```
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:17.36
> ##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'. Finishing: Build solution

The build pipeline task which has been enabled

[image]

I have seen solutions pertaining to local but unsure how this can be fixed on cloud (remote).

P.S strangely the build in local is building successfully.

Answer (score 1):

> Solving ResolveNuGetPackageAssets target error in Build Pipleline of Azure Devops?

First, you need to check if you have added the obj folder to your repo, if yes, you need to delete it from the repo and source control.

Second, you could putting the following snippet into your Framework project file:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BaseOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/out/$(MSBuildProjectName)/bin</BaseOutputPath>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/out/$(MSBuildProjectName)/obj</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Third, since [the Windows Server 2016 with Visual Studio 2017 image is being deprecated](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/hosted-pipelines-image-deprecation/#windows), you could use the `windows-2019` or `windows-2022` instead.

Comment: I tried this unfortunately it's not working. There is no obj folder in the repo. Strangely in one of the other application both the CI and Fortifify build pipeline was failing , the issue in the pipeline was fixed just by upgrading the image to win - 2019.

Comment: deleting obj folder worked for me. thanks!